# How can I process a SQLite dataset in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to process a SQLite dataset in an Android system.

In my dataBaseHelper file (DataBaseAccessor) I have the following code (which when attached to a listview shows the relevant data).

```
public static ArrayList<QuestionListQuestion> getQuestionListQuestions(long id){
String qry = "select QuestionListQuestionID, QuestionListQuestionQuestionListID, QuestionListQuestionQuestionID, QuestionListQuestionSortOrder, QuestionListQuestionSupplementalQuestionIDYes, QuestionListQuestionSupplementalQuestionIDNo, QuestionListQuestionSupplementalQuestionIDText, QuestionListQuestionSurveyGroupID from QuestionListQuestion  where  QuestionListQuestionQuestionListID=" + id;
ArrayList<QuestionListQuestion> list = new ArrayList<QuestionListQuestion>();
try{
    Cursor cursor = wdb.rawQuery(qry, null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
QuestionListQuestion questionlistquestion = new QuestionListQuestion();
    questionlistquestion.QuestionListQuestionID = cursor.getLong(0);
    questionlistquestion.QuestionListQuestionQuestionListID = cursor.getLong(1);
    questionlistquestion.QuestionListQuestionQuestionID = cursor.getLong(2);
    questionlistquestion.QuestionListQuestionSortOrder = cursor.getLong(3);
questionlistquestion.QuestionListQuestionSupplementalQuestionIDYes = cursor.getString(4);       questionlistquestion.QuestionListQuestionSupplementalQuestionIDNo = cursor.getString(5);
questionlistquestion.QuestionListQuestionSupplementalQuestionIDText = cursor.getString(6);
questionlistquestion.QuestionListQuestionSurveyGroupID = cursor.getLong(7);
list.add(questionlistquestion);
}
    cursor.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return list;
}
```

I now need to extend the system so that I can process the data and create new records in another table based on the original list returned.

I tried the following attached to a button (selecting the relevant list ID from a spinner):-

```
QuestionListID = (String) SiteGenerateQuestions.this.spnQuestL.getSelectedItem().toString();
long SpinnerSelectedBT;
SpinnerSelectedBT = GenerateQuestions.this.spnQuestL.getSelectedItemId();
list = DatabaseAccessor.getQuestionListQuestions(SpinnerSelectedBT);
for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
Toast.makeText(SiteGenerateQuestions.this," list.get(" + i + ")   = " + list.get(i) + " "  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Toast displays the following:-

```
list.get(0) =  com.tw.question.entity.QuestionListQuestion@407a6F70
list.get(1) =  com.tw.question.entity.QuestionListQuestion@407bc170
etc...
```

How can I get access to the actual data instead of ... .entity.QuestionListQuestion@407bc170 or am I completely off-track?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @wsanville the `get()` method will return the object in that location of the list. When you print out an object (in a toast, log, System.out.println etc) it will use the `toString()` value in the printout. The default `toString()` is the package name followed by @ which is followed by a hex representation of that object. Your class will need to override the `toString()` method so when you use `get()` it will print out whatever you put in your `toString()` method.

Comment: I'm looking at http://www.javabeat.net/2007/08/overriding-the-tostring-method-in-object-class/ which has given me some idea of where to go from here. 
Any other suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: If I understand right you want access to the objects in the list. If you want access to the objects to manipulate them you will need a reference to them. `ObjectInList itemFromList = list.get(indexNumber)` will give you a reference to the object at `indexNumber`. You can then use `itemsFromList` to call methods from that object.

Comment: Yes, I do want to access the data in the list objects.
I need to retrieve QuestionListQuestionQuestionID, QuestionListQuestionSortOrder and QuestionListQuestionSupplementalQuestionIDYes which I will then use to create a new record in another table. I need the code to run from a button in GenerateQuestions.Java but I call the Query from DatabaseAccessor.Java

For the life of me I can't see how to do it.

Comment: I just keep getting the hashcode and not the data. I can't find any examples on the web, so this is getting really frustrating. If anyone can help further I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi everyone,AS I was struggling so much I decided to rethink.

Comment: The reason I wanted to return the list and then iterate through the list was to generate a new command which proccessed the details and added records in another table. 

After a walk with the dog I though why do I need to add the details after returning the list. So I have now included the record creation in the initial cursor creation. I'm now kicking myself for wasting so much time.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

The output you're seeing is because you haven't implemented the `toString()` method of your `QuestionListQuestion` class. Other than that, it seems like you do have the data you're looking for.  Just try outputting the ID of your object, rather than concatenating the object itself (which will call `toString()` under the hood).

Also, since it looks like you're doing a database operation when a button gets clicked, make sure to do your database operations outside the UI thread. Check out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for a high level overview. You might want to use an `AsyncTask` for your database operation in question.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.
Can you tell me where I should add the     toString()    method?

Comment: and how do I output the ID of the object?

Comment: You can override that method on your `QuestionListQuestion` class, and it looks like you're storing the ID in the `QuestionListQuestionID` member variable.

Comment: I had intended to use an AsyncTask once I have the details ready for processing but I'm still struggling with how I implement both of your suggestions to display the data.